# Substitute for SpatialJoin tool?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, tools

I have to write a script in Arcgis which I would like to use the SpatialJoin tool (arcpy) but I do not have the appropriate extension.

It may be a tool (or example of scripts) for doing the same thing but using the basic license?

Comment: What kind of geometry are we talking about? `Spatial join` has different options for different data types, e.g. Points to Points, Polygon to Points etc

Comment: Are you sure SpatialJoin need any extention? In ArcGIS 9.3, Spatial join is available in ArcVIew licence.

Comment: ArcGIS 9.3 was the last version that [had license restrictions](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_the_Overlay_toolset) on the Spatial Join tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at the [SpatialJoin documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) and there does not seem to be any license restriction on it - at least at 10.1, and it is part of core so does not need an extension either.

Comment: In 10.0 it doesn't need an extension of anything higher that ArcView either: [Spatial Join Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)